# expandablelistview child view vertical line indicator in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter {

```
public Context context;

private LayoutInflater vi;
private String[][] data;
int _objInt;
public static Boolean checked[] = new Boolean[1];


private static final int GROUP_ITEM_RESOURCE = R.layout.list_group;
private static final int CHILD_ITEM_RESOURCE = R.layout.list_item;


public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, String[][] data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    _objInt = data.length;


}

public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return data[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return data[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    String child = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    int id_res = 0;
    if(groupPosition == 0){
        if(childPosition == 0) id_res = R.mipmap.div2;
        if(childPosition == 1) id_res = R.mipmap.div1;

    }
    else if(groupPosition == 1){
        if(childPosition == 0) id_res = R.mipmap.div2;
        if(childPosition == 1) id_res = R.mipmap.div1;
    }
    else if(groupPosition == 2){
        if(childPosition == 0) id_res = R.mipmap.div2;
        if(childPosition == 1) id_res = R.mipmap.div1;
    }
    else if(groupPosition == 3){
        if(childPosition == 0) id_res = R.mipmap.div2;
        if(childPosition == 1) id_res = R.mipmap.div3;
        if(childPosition == 2) id_res = R.mipmap.div1;
    }

    if (child != null) {
        v = vi.inflate(CHILD_ITEM_RESOURCE, null);
        TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image1) ;
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(child));

        imageview.setImageResource(id_res);
    }
    return v;
}

public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return "group-" + groupPosition;
}
public int getGroupCount() {
    return data.length;
}
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    String group = null;
    int id_res = 0;
    long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);
    if(group_id == 0){
        group = "Gate Pass";
        id_res = R.mipmap.getpass;
    }
    else if(group_id == 1){
        group = "Vessel/Rake";
        id_res = R.mipmap.vessel;
    }
    else if(group_id == 2){
        group = "Last leg";
        id_res = R.mipmap.lastleg;
    }
    else if(group_id == 3){
        group = "Other";
        id_res = R.mipmap.other;
    }

    if (group != null) {
        v = vi.inflate(GROUP_ITEM_RESOURCE, null);

        TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image1) ;
        ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.indicatior);
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml(group));
        imageview.setImageResource(id_res);
        if (isExpanded) {

            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow);
        } else {
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow);
        }

    }

    return v;
}
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}
```

}`I want to draw a vertical line for all the child items in a group of an ExpandableListView. My child item is a TextView, so I tried to draw a vertical line in every child TextView, like this:

Comment: @Praful Patel please post your code

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: my code is above @Nisarg

Answer (score 0):

For vertical line add `view` in **xml** file

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

Adjust height according your needs.